# Jmeter thread automatically reducing the number of active threads

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to execute a endurance test for 48 HR with distributed configuration using 100 threads on Jmeter. Initially the thread hold to 100 threads and after that it gradually decreasing after 15-20 min(refer the image attached).

I am running the load simulation on Ubuntu machine using JMeter 5.2. Using three thread group for user distribution(Please refer the image).

Command for triggering the test,

```
nohup bash -c "JVM_ARGS=\"-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -Dnashorn.args=--no-deprecation-warning\" && export JVM_ARGS && ./jmeter -n -t /home/performance/LoadTesting/Apim_Endurance.jmx  -R 192.168.2.32:1099 -GTest_Name=APIM_LoadTest -GTest_Triggered_By=Administrator -GDelete_Scale=1 -Gtest_Id=100CON_48HR_EnduranceTest06" 2>&1 &
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is switching to the [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) where you can specify where and how many threads you want to shut down.

Example configuration which holds 100 users load for 20 minutes and then gradually reduces the load for 47 hours and 40 minutes would be something like:

[image]

You can install Ultimate Thread Group as a part of `Custom Thread Groups` bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]

More information: [How to Ramp Down in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-ramp-down-on-jmeter)